# Applying predicates on a list in Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I am a newbie in SWI-Prolog (5.10.5 running on win 7).

There are 3 files in an application that I am learning about:
a.pl and b.pl and c.pl

a.pl uses the predicate foldl/4, which seems to be in [apply.pl](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/home/swipl/lib/swipl/library/apply.pl?show=src#foldl/4).

c.pl, uses the following:

```
:- ensure_loaded('a.pl').
:- ensure_loaded('b.pl').
```

and then calls some predicates in these files.

When I run c.pl, I get exception that foldl/4 is not defined. I tried adding the following to a.pl:

```
:- use_module(library(apply)).
```

and

```
:- [library(apply)].
```

but no use.

Could you help?

Thanks in advance
Suzi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm running 5.10.4 on Ubuntu, and my version does not have `apply:foldl`, though it does have most of the other predicates in `apply`.  The online source shows that `foldl` was only added on 2012-06-05, but versions 5.10.X are over 2 years old.

So it looks like the online docs are for much newer versions, which you'd need to upgrade to to have this predicate.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there a way to upgrade, or I should unistall and re-install?

Comment: There may be a way to upgrade just the library by itself.  But uninstalling/reinstalling the new version is probably more reliably.